# DriverManager behaves differently in derived tests from Project A and Project B

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, webdriver-manager

I've a C# automation Solution and I have 2 project in it: 
**Project A** contains a `BaseTest` class which creates a driver using `DriverManager`,
and a test class `ProjectATest` that derives from `BaseTest` class.

**Project B** contains a test class `ProjectBTest` which also derives from `BaseTest` class.

## The problem

My Chrome version is 113 while the newest version is 114.
when executing the Project A's test DriverManager creates a driver v113 as expected.
But when executing Project B's test, it creates a driver v114 which causes test failure.

**Exception Message**:

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.129 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

`BaseTest` class: (driver creation)

```cs
namespace Project_A
{
    public class BaseTest
    {
        protected IWebDriver driver;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

`ProjectATest` class:

```cs
namespace Project_A
{
    internal class ProjectATest : BaseTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestA() => Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

`ProjectBTest` class:

```cs
namespace Project_B
{
    internal class ProjectBTest : BaseTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestB() => Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use Firefox but then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution,
According to the `DriverManager` docs:

> You can specify to automatically download a driver matching the version of
> the browser that is installed in your machine (only for Chrome, Edge,
> Firefox and Internet Explorer):

```cs
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```

This solved the problem, but still didn't found an answer to the different behavior between these two projects,
and why it fails in `Project B`.